# GridBackground Charts Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, charts, core-graphics

I hope one of you is champion in pods "Charts". I have problem that i need to have 3 colors in gridBackground at the same time in LineChart. I guess its is impossible without any draw modification. 
Did any of you fight this problem? 
I will be grateful for any help. I think this will be useful also for others

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
  NSArray *gradientColors = @[
                                (id)[ChartColorTemplates colorFromString:@"#00ff0000"].CGColor,
                                (id)[ChartColorTemplates colorFromString:@"#ffff0000"].CGColor
                                ];
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(nil, (CFArrayRef)gradientColors, nil);

    set1.fillAlpha = 1.f;
    set1.fill = [ChartFill fillWithLinearGradient:gradient angle:90.f];
    set1.drawFilledEnabled = YES;

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);

 NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [dataSets addObject:set1];
```